# Android - checking if data connection is actually working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently having a one special use case that I am quite confused how to solve.

We have been checking for internet connection with **ConnectivityService** that has those **ConnectivityType.Wifi** / **ConnectivityType.Mobile** with a property if it is **connected / connecting**. That is all good until you run into following case:

- You have data enabled on your phone.
- Data connection is connected.
- **However** you don't pay for your data bill so you can't make any data transfers.
- (make sure your wifi is turned off while trying this)

I thought that I would simply check as following:

```
private static bool CanReachServer()
        {
            var uri = new Uri(Platform.ApiServerUrl); // replace with https://www.google.com if you like
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
                    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
                    var task = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
                    task.Wait();
                    if (task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Util.Log(string.Format("{0} - {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                return false;
            }
        }
```

But this comes with a result of a successful status 200 - which makes me really confused as I clearly can't access anything data oriented on my phone.

Comment: You should check this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available/ and this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/networkinfo/detect_network_connection/

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thanks, of course I have seen this before, also the first one is related to iOS not to Android :) and as I mentioned I have done the ConnectivityService stuff.

Comment: Second link is for android

Comment: Do you get any data in return, other than a successful connection to the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up implementing following solution that seem to be working quite reliably. You can also enforce reachability on the method.

```
public static NetworkState GetNetworkState(this Context context, bool testReachability = false)
        {
            var result = NetworkState.NoNetwork;

            var connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            var activeNetwork = connMgr.ActiveNetworkInfo;

            if (activeNetwork == null || !activeNetwork.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
            {
                connMgr.Dispose();
                return NetworkState.NoNetwork;
            }

            if (activeNetwork.Type == ConnectivityType.Wifi && activeNetwork.IsConnected)
            {
                if (testReachability)
                {
                    if (CanReachServer())
                        result = NetworkState.WiFi;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = NetworkState.WiFi;
                }
            }
            else if (activeNetwork.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile && activeNetwork.IsConnected)
            {
                if (testReachability)
                {
                    if (CanReachServer())
                        result = NetworkState.Mobile;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = NetworkState.Mobile;
                }
            }

            activeNetwork.Dispose();
            connMgr.Dispose();

            return result;
        }

        private static bool CanReachServer()
        {
            var uri = new Uri(Platform.ApiServerUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (URL url = new URL(uri))
                    {
                        using (HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection())
                        {
                            urlc.SetRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
                            urlc.SetRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                            urlc.ConnectTimeout = 6000;
                            urlc.ReadTimeout = 10000;
                            urlc.Connect();
                            bool result = urlc.ResponseCode == HttpStatus.Ok;
                            urlc.Disconnect();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Util.Log(string.Format("{0} - {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                    return false;
                }
            });
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check connection by attempting to open a socket to a known host - if the connection is successful - you can be sure that you have network access, else you can check the Exception and handle it to show error connection.

```
public bool ActiveInternetConnectivity() {
    try {

        // connect to google on port 80, the HTTP port

        var socket = new Java.Net.Socket("www.google.com", 80);

        // the above would have thrown exception if failed, so we are good

        socket.Close();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        // check logcat to see why it failed, you could then catch and handle each exception independently ( time out, host unknown, end of stream, etc.. )

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);

        // the connection has failed, return false
        return false;
    }
```

---

It's just an idea, codes are not fully tested.

Comment: I have actually tried this before but getting following exception in Xamarin: at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61 \n  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029 \n  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance

Comment: @JakubHolovsky : Point out from where the error occurs. !

Comment: Happens when you are creating a socket var socket = new Java.Net.Socket("www.google.com", 80);